# Co-advise meaning?

Tags: word-meaning

> I'd be happy to **coadvise** with you if that makes either of you more comfortable.

I googled *coadvise* but there weren't  much information.

What does it mean?

Thank you!

Comment: It refers to a context where there are more advisors who work together. Thay  are co-advisors.

Comment: Absolute Beginner is correct. The word **coadvise** is relatively recent jargon, which won't necessarily be found in a dictionary.. The Latinate prefix **co** means "with (someone or something else)".  Compare **cooperate, cohabit**. The verb **advise** means to counsel.

Comment: I'll check my word root dictionary later! I now see the continuity between the sentence above and the other one in my novel. Thanks again!